# Convert a row of data to column with the first 3 VARS used as the prefix

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh, tr

I have been trying to figure this one out via basic scripting, and I keep on running into brickwalls. So, I am asking you guys for help. :)

I have multiple rows of data like this:

> **3A C E** 00B7A 01D1C 01D7E
>   **5A C E** 01D07 01D69 01DCB 01E2D 01E8F
>   **5A C 12** 00B7A 01D1C
>   **5A C 14** 01CFC 01D5E 01DC0 01E22 01E84 01EE6 01F48
>   **5A C 16** 01D0C 01D6E 01DD0 01E32 01E94 01EF6 01F58 01FBA 0201C 0207E 02212 02274
>   **5A C 18** 01D2C 01D8E 01DF0 01E52 01EB4
>   **5A C 1A** 01D3C 01D9E 01E00

This is the output that I need. Each var in that row, after the first 3 vars (prefix ID) needs to have it's own line.

> **3A C E** 00B7A
>   **3A C E** 01D1C
>   **3A C E** 01D7E
>   **5A C E** 01D07
>   **5A C E** 01D69
>   **5A C E** 01DCB
>   **5A C E** 01E2D
>   **5A C E** 01E8F
>   **5A C 12** 00B7A
>   **5A C 12** 01D1C

Thanks in advance,

Pit

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i}' file
3A C E 00B7A
3A C E 01D1C
3A C E 01D7E
5A C E 01D07
5A C E 01D69
5A C E 01DCB
5A C E 01E2D
5A C E 01E8F
5A C 12 00B7A
5A C 12 01D1C
[...snip...]
```

#### How it works

```
for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i
```

This starts a `for` loop.  `NF` is the number of columns on the line.   In the loop, `i` runs from 4 to `NF`.  For each value of `i`, we print the first column, second column, third column, and column `i`.